# Trying to use Timesynchronizer...getting compile error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to use Timesynchronizer...getting compile error. Do not know what the error is telling me.  Changed pgm to use ConstPtrs still same error:

It seem based on this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function  Timesycronizer and other boost type templates are not officially supported by ROS within a class member function. Is my understand correct? If this is true what other interface to these functions is supported? Can the tutorial be updated to show how to use these in member functions or state that they are not available.

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf2_ros
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  )

catkin_package(
  DEPENDS boost
  LIBRARIES
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  tf2_ros
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  )
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h>
#include <control_msgs/JointControllerState.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>


using namespace control_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

class PublishOdometry
{
public:
  PublishOdometry()
  {

     count=0;
     motor_position_joint1_new =0;
     motor_position_joint1_old =0;
     motor_position_joint2_new =0;
     motor_position_joint2_old =0;
     x = 0;               
     y = 0;
     theta = 0;

     pubOdometry = n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 10);

     // Listen and wait for initial pose from nav
     subInitialPose = n.subscribe("/initialpose", 1, 
           &PublishOdometry::handelerInitialPose,this);
  }

void handelerOdometry(const JointControllerStateConstPtr& msg1, const JointControllerStateConstPtr& msg2)
{
     double wheel_track = 0.4;   //distance between two wheels

     motor_position_joint1_new = msg1->process_value;
     motor_position_joint2_new = msg2->process_value;

     ROS_INFO("J1PV=%f  J2PV=%f",motor_position_joint1_new, motor_position_joint2_new);


     if (timeold.toSec()==0)  // skip first set of joint cmd
     {
       timeold = msg1->header.stamp;
       motor_position_joint1_old = motor_position_joint1_new;
       motor_position_joint2_old = motor_position_joint2_new;
       return; 
     }

     float j1 = (motor_position_joint1_new - motor_position_joint1_old); 
     float j2 = (motor_position_joint2_new - motor_position_joint2_old);

     motor_position_joint1_old = motor_position_joint1_new;
     motor_position_joint2_old = motor_position_joint2_new;

     double  dt = (msg1->header.stamp - timeold).toSec();  // elapsed time in seconds
     float   distance =    ( ((j1 + j2)*dt) / 2.0);             // distance in meters
     float   dtheta   =    ( ((j1 - j2)*dt) / wheel_track);     // rotation
   
     double dx = (distance*sin(dtheta));
     double dy = (distance*cos(dtheta)); 

     theta =  (theta+dtheta); //fmodf((theta+dtheta),(2*M_PI));                   
     x = x + dx;
     y = y + dy;

     ROS_INFO("x=%e  y=%e theta=%f ddtheta=%f ",x,y,theta, dtheta);

     timeold = msg1->header.stamp;    // new old time

     geometry_msgs::Quaternion  quaternion;
     quaternion.x = 0.0;
     quaternion.y = 0.0; 
     quaternion.z = sin(theta/2);          // set yaw
     quaternion.w = cos(theta/2);

     geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
     odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
     odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";
     odom_trans.header.stamp =  timeold;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0; 
     odom_trans.transform.rotation = quaternion;

     odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);
 
     nav_msgs::Odometry odometry;
     odometry.header.frame_id = "odom";
     odometry.child_frame_id  = "base_link";
     odometry.header.stamp    = timeold;

     odometry.pose.pose.position.x  = distance;
     odometry.pose.pose.position.y  = y;
     odometry.pose.pose.position.z  = 0;
     odometry.pose.pose.orientation = quaternion;
     odometry.twist.twist.linear.x  = x;
     odometry.twist.twist.linear.y  = 0;
     odometry.twist.twist.angular.z = ((theta)*(M_PI/180));  // convert to radians

     pubOdometry.publish(odometry);

     calculateJointState(motor_position_joint1_old,"joint1");
     calculateJointState(motor_position_joint2_old,"joint2");
}



void calculateJointState(const float pv, const std::string name)
{
     sensor_msgs::JointState jointStateMsg;
     jointStateMsg.name.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.position.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.velocity.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
     jointStateMsg.header.stamp = timeold;
     jointStateMsg.name[0] = name;
     jointStateMsg.position[0] = pv;
     jointStateMsg.velocity[0] = 0.0;
     pubJointState.publish(jointStateMsg);
}




void handelerInitialPose(geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr msg)
{
     geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
     odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
     odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";
     odom_trans.header.stamp =  msg->header.stamp;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
     odom_trans.transform.translation.z = msg->pose.pose.position.z;
     odom_trans.transform.rotation = msg->pose.pose.orientation;

     odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);
 
     nav_msgs::Odometry odometry;
     odometry.header.frame_id = "odom";
     odometry.child_frame_id  = "base_link";
     odometry.header.stamp    = msg->header.stamp;
     odometry.pose.pose.position = msg->pose.pose.position;
     odometry.pose.pose.orientation = msg->pose.pose.orientation;

     pubOdometry.publish(odometry);

     // Listen for motor control response
     Subscriber<JointControllerState> j1_sub(n, "/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/state", 1);
     Subscriber<JointControllerState> j2_sub(n, "/rrbot/joint2_position_controller/state", 1);
     TimeSynchronizer<JointControllerState, JointControllerState> sync(j1_sub, j2_sub, 10);
     sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&PublishOdometry::handelerOdometry, _1, _2));

     ROS_INFO("handelerInitialPose finished processing");
}



private:

   double x,y,count;
   float motor_position_joint1_new;
   float motor_position_joint1_old;
   float motor_position_joint2_new;
   float motor_position_joint2_old;
   float theta;
   ros::Time timeold;
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Publisher pubOdometry;
   tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;
   ros::Publisher  pubJointState;
   ros::Subscriber subInitialPose;
   ros::Subscriber j1_sub;
   ros::Subscriber j2_sub;



};  // Enodof Class



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_odometry");

  PublishOdometry sp;

  // send static latch transformations 

  tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;

  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg.transform.rotation.x =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.y =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.z =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.w =  1.0;

  msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
  msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.z = 0.2;
  msg.child_frame_id = "hokuyo_frame";
  static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);

  msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
  msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.z = 0.3;
  msg.child_frame_id = "camera_frame";
  static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

ERROR FOLLOWS:::::

```
   uilding CXX object gazebo_ros_demos/rrbot_control/CMakeFiles/robot_odometry.dir/src/robot_odometry.cpp.o
[100%] [100%] Built target robot_twist_to_vel
Built target robot_jntcmd_to_jntst
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/rrbot_control/src/robot_odometry.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >’
/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/rrbot_control/src/robot_odometry.cpp:162:82:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:92,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/forwards.h:39,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/rrbot_control/src/robot_odometry.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker9<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:907:60:   required from ‘void boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::function9(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1042:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/signal9.h:281:98:   required from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Signal9<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::addCallback(C&) [with C = const boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (PublishOdometry::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; M0 = control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = control_msgs::JointControllerState_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83316/trying-to-use-timesynchronizer...getting-compile-error/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-09-26**:
I think your problem might be related to how boost::bind works with member functions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-26**:
It seem based on this reference  Timesycronizer and other boost type templates are not officially supported by ROS within a class member function. Is my understand correct?  If this is true what other interface to these functions is supported.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-26**:
Yes...I tried adding it to several places....a working example would be great

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-26**:
@georgebrindeiro is right. `this` is missing in the `bind()`. Every **method of a class** actually has extra argument which is the pointer to the instance of that class. When the method is called within another method of a class, `this` is passed implicitly. ROS require callback functions to have certain number of arguments, but it has no idea about the host class. So, when the callback is called the only parameters to be passed there are the messages and `this` is not provided. However your function can not work without `this`, because it will have no access to any of the class members. So `boost::bind` simply allows you to pass it as additional argument. Since you didn't do it the compiler complained.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-26**:
Replacing the line for `sync.registerCallback()` with the `sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&PublishOdometry::handelerOdometry, this, _1, _2));` should be sufficient.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-27**:
This solution worked and the code now compiles...thank you. How can this solution get into the tutorial so others like myself who are not steeped in c++ will not repeat this. Also can you make this an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried adding `this` to the `boost::bind` function call? That's what they usually require for binding member functions. That might be the only thing missing.

Citing Boris' comment, this is how you would do it:

```
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&PublishOdometry::handelerOdometry, this, _1, _2));
```

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soroosh129](https://answers.ros.org/users/30568/soroosh129/) on 2019-07-05**:
Wow thank you! Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a quick glance you are specifying wrong argument types for `calculateOdometry()`. Instead of `const JointControllerState`, you should use `const JointControllerStateConstPtr&` (note **ConstPtr&** at the end). So, all the message callbacks in ROS accepting `boost::shared_ptr` as the arguments.

Although passing arguments by reference is not mandatory, it is recommended and considered as a good style.

Please also note that template arguments **should not** be pointers, but the types of the messages themselves. So simply fixing the callback function arguments will be enough to make it compile.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-26**:
I have made these changes and I am still getting a compile error. Can this be some kind of compiler environment issue?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-09-26**:
What I learn from my past experience (and I didn't manage to make it work), the timestamps of those to be synchronized have to match 'exactly'. Perhaps this is also the culprit in your case.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-26**:
@alfa_80, the problem that you are talking about is a runtime problem, but the question is about compilation. Anyway, you are right, the time stamps should be exactly same. To deal with misaligned time stamps there is ApproximateTime message filter: http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-09-27**:
@Boris: You're right.